# Stored image in database doesn't show on page

Tags: php, mysql, image, jpeg

Image is stored in database (as varchar(255)), but on page isn't shown.

This is code that stored image, and put's image in folder:

```
if (isset($_FILES["image"])) {
    $title = date("dmyHms") . "_" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];
    $path = "img/profile/" . $_POST["id"] . "_" . $title;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $path);

}
```

And this is to display image:

```
foreach ($conn->results() as $conn):
    $img = $_SERVER["CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . $path . "img/profile" . $conn->id . "_" . $conn->image;
    if (file_exists($img)) {
    $image = $path . "img/profile/" . $conn->id . "_" . $conn->image;
    } else {
    $image = $path . "img/noimage.png";
    }
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

When I print_r $img, it shows right path to image and still image is not displayed.

Display:

```
<?php echo $image; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where did you echoing your image? If it is inside foreach, you need to change your code little bit...

```
$image = '<img src="'.$path . "img/profile/" . $conn->id . "_" . $conn->image . '" />';
```

Hope, will work perfectly for you.... TQ

Comment: Now nothing is shown, just blank.. before there was alt icon

Comment: `'<img src="' .$path . 'img/profile/' . $conn->id . '_' . $conn->image . ' " />';`

Try by that one. And of course, you need to echo $image variable. If rest of your code will work, surely you will get positive answer.

Comment: I get: /nominal/img/noimage.png, no image show just that

Comment: Still having same problem, image does not display... And if I remove image else part won't show noimage...

Comment: it should not be. Basically it is working with me perfectly... Check properly whether you write code correctly or not.

Answer (score 0):

The following line is not correct:

```
foreach ($conn->results() as $conn):
```

Don't overwrite `$conn`. Change the variable to something different like `$result`